# CSS 3D rotation around Y axis causes blinking of the rotated content in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, rotation

I have a trouble in Chrome with the rotated content which has style -webkit-transform: rotateY( 180deg ).

If the content has white background color, it blinks, but if it has background-color: transparent, blinking disappears during the rotation. It's probably a bug which I try to work with but sometimes this way leads to nothing.

Is there any appropriate method to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you post an example where this is happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation is like that [card flip](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/card-01.html) but I have more complicated mark up for the cards. Here, for the card number 2 which is faced back the style is -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) and for other card the style is empty. For the card number 1 I wrote -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) what removed blining during the css rotation -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s .